# Ubuntu issue setting up autoconf and automake

Tags: ubuntu, installation, autoconf, automake

I am trying to install the autoconf and automake tools on the latest Ubuntu but I am having problems finding anything online that will help me do this, I've tried to do apt-get update but I am having no luck.  I need these tools in order to install a machine translation program. So my question is how exactly do I  install both of these.

Comment: You need the autotools to build a tarball for the program you want to install, but you do not need them to install the program  unless the program's distribution system is horribly broken.  Get a tarball and install it.  If you cannot do that, report it as a bug to the maintainer of the machine translation program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably more appropriate to ask on: http://askubuntu.com.  But all you should have to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install automake autoconf
```